# Phpmailer: multiple dynamic attachments in one form

Tags: php, html, forms, phpmailer

I am creating a mailing-list service.
I need to attach dynamically one or more files into an email, using php, phpmailer and only one "slot" for adding files in the html form.
I just know how to send one attachment, not two or more, in the same email.

here u are the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="main_container">

            <form action="phpmailer/sendmail.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="prenota">

                    <div class="form_title">
                        <h2>Mailing List</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form_title">
                        <p>Message:</p>
                    </div>

                    <label for="message">
                        <textarea name="message"></textarea>
                    </label>

                    <label for="file">
                        Select one or more file to send
                        <input name="file" type="file" id="file_ok">
                    </label>

                    <div class="submit-container">
                        <input class="submit-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Invia"><br>
                    </div>

                </form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the php for the phpmailer (sendmail.php, it works with the hosting service I am usign):

```
<?php 
require_once('libs/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');


$db= new PDO('mysql:host=00.000.000.000;dbname=dbname_1', 'dbname', 'dbpass');//connection setup

$m_list = $db->query("
    SELECT id, nome, email
    FROM mailing_list
")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


$mail             = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';


//variables
$email_receiver =  $m_list['email'];  
$name_receiver = $m_list['nome'];

$nome_sender= "mr x"; 
$messagge= stripslashes($_POST['message']);

foreach ($m_list as $eachmail) {

    $email_receiver =  $eachmail['email'];  
    $name_receiver = $eachmail['nome'];

    $mail->From = "service@email.it";   

    $mail->FromName = "service";            

    $mail->AddReplyTo($email_receiver, $name_receiver);

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail->AddAddress($email_receiver, "dynamic name");  

    $mail->Subject    = "Message from website";   

    $body             = '<strong>email send to:</strong> ' . $name_receiver . '<br/>
                    <strong>email:</strong> ' . $email_receiver . '<br/>
                    <strong>message:</strong> ' . stripslashes($message) . '<br/><br/>';

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $mail->Send(true);
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients(true);

}

echo "mail sent";

?>
```

I imagine I need to store the files ito an array and then, for each files, create the relative attachment. Unfortunately I can't. Any help?

Comment: Base your code on a combination of the [mailing list example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) and the [send upload example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) provided with PHPMailer. Essentially you just need to call `addAttachment` for each file after processing the uploads.

Comment: Thaks, I did what u suggested me, posting an answer too!

Comment: phpmailer couldn't care less how many/few attachments you're doing. you just call `->AddAttachment()` until you're done adding. if you don't call it at all, then that's fine too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I used an "injection" of Jquery, in order to add as much as inputs file I want in the dom of the main form, and to delete them if desired.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( '#add_more' ).click(function() {
        var current_count = $('input[type="file"]').length;
        var next_count = current_count +1;
        $('#prenota').prepend('<p id="here_' + next_count + '"><input type="file" name="file_' + next_count + '" /></p>')
        $('#here_' + next_count + '').append('<a class="delete_this" href="#">delete</a>');
    });


    $('.delete_this').live('click', function(){
        var current_todelete = $(this).closest("p").attr("id"); 
        $('#' + current_todelete + '').remove();
    });
});
```

Then I added some strings in the php file designated to collect post information and sendig emails, making it capable to carry attachments (as Synchro suggested me):

```
if (isset($_FILES)){
    foreach ($_FILES as $file) {

        $filename = $file['name'];
        $filetype = $file['type'];
        $filetmp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
        $filesize = $file['size'];

        if($filename){
            $temPath = '../../../../../public/' . basename($filename);

            //var_dump($temPath);
            //die();

            if (move_uploaded_file($filetmp_name, $temPath)) {
                $mail->AddAttachment($temPath, $filename);
            }
        }       
    }
}else{
    $mail->AddAttachment(false);
}
```

Hoping to be helpful to people with the same problem of mine.

Comment: Glad it worked, but this file handling isn't safe - do it the way the send upload example uses - call `move_uploaded_file` first, and don't trust submitted filenames.

Comment: Synchro, I modified the code in my answer as u suggested to me, does it be right, now?
If I use "tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name']))" line scritp u shown in the linked example, it reluts impossible to send a valid file. The file is sent correctly, but corrupted.
Why is necessary to process the file within move_uploaded_file method? In order to prevent my mailinglist be considered as spamming?

Comment: All that does is generate a safe, unique temporary filename. It doesn't send anything or move any files. The next line is the important one. If you want to know why you need to do this, read the PHP file uploading docs that are also linked from that example.